# How to detect client cancellation for a grpc streaming response from the server side

Tags: python, grpc

Here is the method in the Servicer class(simplified)

```
    def getNMEA(self, request, context):
        '''
        Need to open a new stream
        '''
        publisher = Publisher()
        publisher.start()
        while True:
            msg = publisher.get_message()
            if msg is None:
                break
            yield msg
```

The method needs to know that the client is gone.

I have been through the gRPC documentation, but did not found where to register for a callback or catch an exception.